# Pandas groupby().rolling(window,closet).std() return NaN for all other groups except the first group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

[DataFrame format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1cAH.png)

Here is the DataFrame format, and I would like to rolling calculate the std of returns based on the previous 5 days returns(exclude current day) for each stock_code.

[What I try here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swriH.png)

While, after 'groupby'and 'rolling' calculating for the std, the result only gives me the correct answer for the first group(stock_code == 0000001).

[This issue only happends in some cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWuiy.png)

For any other functions except .std(), it returns the correct result.

[Drop the parameter closet='left'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtNOr.png)

What is more, if I drop the parameter closet='left', which means it will include the data on current day, the result looks like correct(but that is not what I expect).

Can someone gives me some hints to handle this issue?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You must replace all your images with reproducible text, and minimized datasets (only a few rows)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bug in old version. See issues here. At least, it was fixed in 1.5.3

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42442